# websocket connectiion failed

Tags: javascript, websocket, java-websocket

I don't understand why I have the error below in the console for whichever website I visit. I did not write any script to do with webSocket and I have little knowledge about it. Where is the reload file coming from?

```
reload.js:22 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000//ws' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
init @ reload.js:22
(anonymous) @ reload.js:65
```

** **In the reload file** **

```
   socket = new WebSocket(address);
    socket.onmessage = (msg) => {
        reloadWindow(msg, data)
    };
```

Comment: Could this be coming from some kind of browser extension used for development? Because it sounds like part of a mechanism that'll conveniently reload the page during development after you've changed and saved your code

Comment: @ChrisG May it could be the live server web extension. I once used it though it has been weeks since I started it. perhaps it still works in the background.

Comment: @ChrisG Of course it was the live server web extension I turned it of and the error is gone.